# Ambari Agent Registration failed due to unsupported OS type

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I was using Ambari Server UI to register a node as an agent and the registration kept failing. I checked the ambari-agent logs at `/var/log/ambari-agent/` and found the following line in the logs
`Registration failed due to: Cannot register host with not supported os type, hostname=scope, serverOsType=ubuntu19, agentOsType=ubuntu19`

I understand this is because I have Ubuntu 19.04. Is this any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the answer, it is an ambari version problem so apply this solution to you it works

If you want to give it a try, the list of os and their versions supported by ambari can be found under this path ( on Ambari server host and on Ambari agent hosts )

/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/ambari_commons/resources/os_family.json
or
/usr/lib/ambari-server/lib/ambari_commons/resources/os_family.json

You can add the ambari version you are using and restart ambari

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the ambari version you are using doesn't support this version of ubuntu: this means in reality that ambari is not yet officially tested against that version.

If you want to give it a try, the list of os and their versions supported by ambari can be found under this path ( on Ambari server host and on Ambari agent hosts )

`/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/ambari_commons/resources/os_family.json`
or
`/usr/lib/ambari-server/lib/ambari_commons/resources/os_family.json`

You can add the ambari version you are using and restart ambari